# Why isnt my label displaying any text after the user exits and comes back to app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, label

This is my code for displaying text to label, it works well before the app is closed:

```
 var def = UserDefaults.standard
    else if self.hintO == 1{
                    var arr = [Character]()
                    let str = String(self.answers[self.numQues])
                    for i in str{
                        arr.append(i)
                    }
                    let first = arr[0]
                    self.label.text = String(first)
                    for i in 0...self.buttonsArray.count-1{
                        if self.buttonsArray[i].titleLabel!.text! == String(first){
                            self.buttonsArray[i].isHidden = true
                            self.slow.append(self.buttonsArray[i])
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    self.coins -= 12
                    self.lobel.text = "Coins: \(self.coins)"
                    self.def.set(self.coins, forKey: "coins")
                    self.hintO += 1
                    let ggo = String(first)
                    self.def.set(self.hintO, forKey: "hintss")
                    self.def.set(ggo, forKey: "firstTing")
                }
```

This is my other code in function viewdidappear function. This is the code that I use when user exits my app.

```
if let vokds = def.object(forKey: "hintss") as? Int{
        hintO = vokds
        print(hintO)
        if hintO == 2{
            if let sdkf = def.object(forKey: "firstTing") as? String{ print(sdkf)
                label.text = "\(sdkf)"
                print("Its working")
            }
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is not consistent, you are using different  label names in both the function. (i.e `lobel` vs `label`)

Another thing is that you are trying to set `String(first)` into the user defaults which might be optional value, so try printing the `UserDefault` value before setting it to the label.

Use `UserDefault` value to show it on label in both the functions that way you will be able to understand whether you are setting correct value in storage or not.

Comment: Yes, print the value before use/setting to the label.

Comment: I did, the value prints what I want tho, but label does not work

Comment: Can you please update your code with added print statement?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that.

Comment: I try to print the text to "label" but it is not working